# Is the PyPy question really opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

It's about this question:

> [Why shouldn't I use PyPy over CPython if PyPy is 6.3 times faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946662/why-shouldnt-i-use-pypy-over-cpython-if-pypy-is-6-3-times-faster)

This question is set "On hold" because

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

However, the question does not ask for opinions. The question reads for me like

> The advantages of PyPy are X and Y. But what are the downsides of it?

The highest voted answer points out what the downsides are (from personal experience). Not an entirely-opinion-based-post in my eyes.

Why was this question put on hold?

To clarify, I don' say that I agree or disagree with this decision. I just want to know why this question is considered as a not good Q&A format.

Comment: Why is X better than Y are always closed, they never end well. Everyone has their favourite and will argue to death that it is better. See [gorilla-vs-shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)

Comment: Also; how has that question been viewed 33627 since yesterday! Thats insane

Comment: Well, the Meta-effect will strike again and reopen this question for the 3rd time.

Comment: @RichardTingle: hackernews

Comment: @RichardTingle It is/was one of the hot question in the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™.

Comment: This questions used to scream "poll" to me ("Is PyPy better than CPython?"), but now it looks like just asking for a list. Seems less subjective since it was reworked, but to my mind there's still a very high chance of subjective answers and I find it unlikely we'll get a single authoritative answer.

Comment: I personally think it should be closed as "too broad" because it is a list question.

Comment: Argh. And the close/reopen cicle has finished the 4rd round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based by Stephan Eggermont, Joshua Taylor, Jeroen, Eric Brown, Jim Garrison 5 hours ago

Because those users considered it opinion-based.

There are already two reopen votes pending so with all the attention that question gets I'd expect it to be re-opened soon. With non-binding votes it would be three now, but I have reopened this question once before (after it was mod-closed and reworded slightly afterwards to make it more clear it's not asking for opinions) so I won't override the community decision this time.

Comment: I'm sure there is a more appropriate blog post somewhere for them to discuss PyPy vs CPython...

Answer (score 4):

It will always be opinionated. It will never be up to date. Please, some moderator, lock it.

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: *"Is the PyPy question really opinion-based?"* Um, yes it does.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be locked. It's not a spam post or something else that cannot be handled by the community.